Volume between an Oblique Cylinder and a vertical Plane. Double or Triple Integrals?
I am working on an archeology projet and i need to cuantify some areas and Volumes of some figures. In this case i need to measure a part of an oblique cylinder.
An Oblique Cylinder with elliptical base $\frac{x^2}{2^2} + \frac{y^2}{6^2} = 1$, and the generatrix  $9{x^2} + {y^2} + 9{z^2} + 6zy = 36$
is cut by the vertical plane $y=3$.
We need to know the Volume between this surfaces: Plane and oblique cylinder.
How is the Integral Double or Triple?
What are the limits of integrals knowing that:
Height (z) varies between 0 and 1
Length (y) varies between 3 and 6
Width (x) varies between  $-\sqrt{3}$  and $\sqrt{3}$.
Paste Image

Note that double integral $\iint_D f, dA$ can be understand as the volumne under $f$ over the region $D$. Triple integral $\iiint_R 1, dV$ is just the volumne of $R$. For this question, I will choose to use the triple integral

Also note that triple integral will be easier, because the function is in implicit form

By the way: your second formula is different from that appearing in the figure: which is the correct one?

Oh i forget the 9 before $x^2$    It is 9 $x^2$

Volume between elliptical vertical cylinder and generatrix can be found in following way: as $-2 \leqslant x  \leqslant 2$ for elliptical base and for generatrix $(3z+y)^2+x^2=36\quad (1)$ we have $-6 \leqslant x  \leqslant 6$, then elliptical vertical cylinder lies "inside" generatrix and we can find roof and floor from $(1)$. So, volume without $y=3$ restriction will be
$$\iint\limits_{\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{36} \leqslant 1}\ \int\limits_{(-y-\sqrt{36-x^2})\cdot \frac 1 3}^{(-y+\sqrt{36-x^2})\cdot \frac 1 3}dzdxdy$$
To take into account the $y=3$, you need to clarify that you are interested in the figure below or above (in relation to $y$) this plane.
Addition.
Outgoing from your comment if you want to calculate volume above $xy$ plane, then this gives floor $z=0$ and if you would like to take $3 \leqslant y$, then we need to find intersection points of $y=3$ and elliptical vertical cylinder which gives $x=\pm \sqrt 3$. So, we obtain
$$\int\limits_{-\sqrt 3}^{\sqrt 3}\int\limits_{3}^{6\cdot \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}}\ \int\limits_{0}^{(-y+\sqrt{36-x^2})\cdot \frac 1 3}dzdydx$$

Thanks for the answer. I am interested in the region of the cylinder ABOVE the xy plane and the vertical plane y=3

Added a response to your clarification. By the way, if it's not a big secret, what is this thing - is it a real-life problem? Mathematicians are usually happy when their games have real-life applications.

Of course not. I am working on an archeology project and we have to quantify a lot of surfaces with their volumes, areas and heights. Some figures are not easily accessible

Sorry @zkutch I made a mistake when writing the second equation: The correct is 9 $x^2$.  I forget to write the 9. Thank you so much

Last question @zkutch:  The order dzdxdy is correct? Why not dzdydx  I don´t understand why if x varies from -$\sqrt{3}$ to +$\sqrt{3} and it is in first integral dx is not the last differencial?

You are right $dx$ should be last. Corrected. Thank You.

Each double integral is triple integral since
$$\iint_D(f_2(x,y)-f_1(x,y))dydx\\=\iint_D\int_{f_1(x,y)}^{f_2(x,y)}dzdydx.$$
So, the answer of your question is either both or triple integral.
Zkutch answer can be written as a double integral
$$\iint\limits_{\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{36} \leqslant 1\\3\leq y\leq6}\ \frac23\sqrt{36-x^2}dxdy$$
with the choice of smaller $D$.
He actually found $z_{top}=f_2(x,y)$ and $z_{bottom}=f_1(x,y)$ by solving generatrix equation by quadratic formula:
$$9z^2+6yz+x^2+y^2-36=0$$
$$z=\frac{-6y\pm\sqrt{(6y)^2-4(9)(x^2+y^2-36)}}{2(9)}$$
$$z=\frac{-y\pm\sqrt{36-x^2}}{3}$$
